# How to get sum total of particular column from two different tables and print it

Tags: mysql

```
select sum(Qty) AS QUANTITY
from purchase
where ItemName='$iname',
      sum(quantity) AS QUANTITY1
      from dispatch
      where ItemName='$iname';
```

If I run this query separately I am getting result if I run above query getting syntax error

> 1064 - syntax error next to 'sum(Qty) AS QUANTITY1 from dispatch where
>   ItemName='$iname'' Ã  la ligne 1

Comment: What is linking `purchase` and `dispatch`?

Comment: both are different tables but have values of purchase and dispatch means sales I would like to calculate available quantity and also i would like to print total dispatched and total purchased quantity I will calculate the difference in HTML form just want sum total of purchased and dispatched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As columns:

```
select  
    (select sum(Qty) AS QUANTITY from purchase where ItemName='$iname') AS QUANTITY, 
    (select sum(quantity) AS QUANTITY1 from dispatch where ItemName='$iname') AS QUANTITY1
```

Comment: Error

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 169
STR: '
SQL: select (select sum(Qty) AS QUANTITY from purchase where ItemName='BOOK') AS QUANTITY,(select sum(quantity) AS QUANTITY1 from dispatch where itemname='BOOK') AS QUANTITY1';


SQL query: Documentation

select (select sum(Qty) AS QUANTITY from purchase where ItemName='BOOK') AS QUANTITY,(select sum(quantity) AS QUANTITY1 from dispatch where itemname='BOOK') AS QUANTITY1';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 -

Comment: Sorry I am accurate getting results will you please let me know how to print it?

Comment: I want to print it in php like echo

Comment: Ho Alex thanks, its working, is it possible to subtract QUANTITY - QUANTITY1       in the same query?        I mean I would like show the Available stock

Comment: Hi I got it select (select sum(Qty) AS QUANTITY from purchase where ItemName='iname') AS QUANTITY, (select sum(quantity) AS QUANTITY1 from dispatch where ItemName='iname') AS QUANTITY1, (select QUANTITY - QUANTITY1) as AVAILABLE